# SQLcmd output contains also unwanted input SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I created a sql script that retrieve some information from database as a table format,

I have create a sqlcmd script that execute that query file, 
but in the output file I have the queries present in the .sql file + the results that are saved, 
result file http://prntscr.com/7e4j5i

I want only to have the result in that file

```
SQLCMD -S pcname\SQLEXPRESS -v VITI=%vl% -E -w 166 -e -i C:\db\input.sql -o C:\db\Book1.csv -s","  -w 700 -es
```

How can I do it?

Do I have to change something in the .sql file to exclude the queries from the results file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-e` parameter.

The `-e` parameter will echo the input (i.e. your SQL).

For info, see [here](http://www.sqlserverspecialists.com/2012/10/sqlcmd-command-line-option.html).